# Multiple insert with one list of int

Tags: sql, sql-server-2008, t-sql

Here I have a list of ids provided by one SELECT, and one simple insert example

```
SELECT idUnit FROM dbo.GetUnitsTree(10)

INSERT INTO [Profession_Ext]
           ([FK_Personnal]
           ,[FK_Profession])
     VALUES
           (50
           ,<FK_Profession, int,>)
```

I want the same result that this, but dynamically (I want to script this)

```
INSERT INTO [Profession_Ext]
               ([FK_Personnal]
               ,[FK_Profession])
         VALUES
               (50,1),(50,2),(50,3),(50,4),(50,5),(50,6),(50,7),(50,8)
```

Where 50 is a fixed value.

How to do?

Comment: you can go for cursor also.

Comment: If sql server 2008 supports table value parameters, that's the approach I would use.

Comment: Where do the _variable_ values (1, 2, 3, ...) come from? A function, e.g. `dbo.GetUnitsTree`, a variable, e.g. `@idList = '1,2,3'`, ... ?

Comment: What datatype does dbo.GetUnitsTree return?   What problem are you trying to solve?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> Here I have a dynamic list of int (provided by a SELECT)

I would either insert directly from the original `SELECT` if you don't need the results for anything other than the INSERT:

```
INSERT INTO Profession_Ext
([FK_Personnal] ,[FK_Profession])
SELECT {select list here}
```

or change your SELECT to populate a temp table and then pull from that:

```
SELECT {select list here}
INTO @tmpResults

INSERT INTO Profession_Ext
([FK_Personnal] ,[FK_Profession])
SELECT 50, FK_Profession
FROM @tmpResults
```

Answer (score 3):

Write following one Bulk Insertion with Select statement:

```
INSERT INTO [Profession_Ext] ([FK_Personnal] ,[FK_Profession])
SELECT 50 AS [FK_Personnal], tbl.[FK_Profession] 
FROM (
    SELECT 1 AS FK_Profession 
    UNION ALL SELECT 2
    UNION ALL SELECT 3
    UNION ALL SELECT 4
    UNION ALL SELECT 5
    UNION ALL SELECT 6
    UNION ALL SELECT 7
    UNION ALL SELECT 8
) AS tbl
```

Comment: but 1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8 is dynamic!

Comment: @clement You do realise that you can replace the `SELECT 1 ... SELECT 8` by any other `SELECT` query? You stated in your question that your values from from a `SELECT`...

Answer (score -1):

**First** create a function that `return a table value` .. `like below`

```
    CREATE FUNCTION [dbo].[SplitStringToInt] 
   (
     @LIST      VARCHAR(MAX) ,
     @DELIMITER VARCHAR(5)=null 
   ) 
   RETURNS @TABLEOFVALUES TABLE 
      (  
         [VALUE] int 
      ) 
AS 
   BEGIN

    set @DELIMITER=isnull(@DELIMITER,',')

      DECLARE @LENSTRING INT 

      WHILE LEN( @LIST ) > 0 
         BEGIN 

            SELECT @LENSTRING = 
               (CASE CHARINDEX( @DELIMITER, @LIST ) 
                   WHEN 0 THEN LEN( @LIST ) 
                   ELSE ( CHARINDEX( @DELIMITER, @LIST ) -1 )
                END
               ) 

            INSERT INTO @TABLEOFVALUES 
               SELECT convert(int,SUBSTRING( @LIST, 1, @LENSTRING ))

            SELECT @LIST = 
               (CASE ( LEN( @LIST ) - @LENSTRING ) 
                   WHEN 0 THEN '' 
                   ELSE RIGHT( @LIST, LEN( @LIST ) - @LENSTRING - 1 ) 
                END
               ) 
         END

      RETURN 

   END
```

**Then**  you can use it like ...

```
INSERT INTO [Profession_Ext] ([FK_Personnal] ,[FK_Profession])
select 50 A,VALUE from dbo.SplitStringToInt('1,2,3,4,5,6',',')
```